# Apache encodes URL while rewriting

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, url, encoding

I'm having troubles with URL rewriting. My rules work well but they encode GET parameters.

**/myurl/search?text=accès** becomes **/myurl/search?text=acc%25C3%25A8s**

My search engine cannot work with this parameter and i cannot pass them in POST method. How can I get rid of that encoding ?

Here is the content of my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^var/.* - [L]
RewriteRule ^design/.* - [L]
RewriteRule ^share/icons/.* - [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemaps/.* - [L]
RewriteRule ^kernel/.* - [L]
RewriteRule ^extension/.* - [L]
RewriteRule ^packages/styles/.* - [L]
RewriteRule vols/redirect - [L]

RewriteRule ow_gmapdata/.* /index_ajax.php [L]
RewriteRule adlMenu/.* /index_ajax.php [L]
RewriteRule vols/.* /index_ajax.php [L]
RewriteRule adlCarrousel/.* /index_ajax.php [L]
RewriteRule retro-planning/.* /index_ajax.php [L]
RewriteRule opodo/.* /index_ajax.php [L]
RewriteRule adlformparamhandler/.* /index_ajax.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index_ajax\.php - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?([^/].*)?$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found it !

I needed the flag **NE** on the main rewrite rule :

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?([^/].*)?$ /$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```